# How to solve equality between N'سلام' and N'سـلام' in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, collation, farsi

When I'm trying to compare two words like N'سلام' and N'سـلام' in SQL Server, there is no difference.

```sql
select 
case 
    when 
        N'سـلام' = N'سلام'
            then 1 
            else 0 
end
```

I've tried to solve the problem by setting the collation of two words, but not working.

```sql
select 
case 
    when 
        N'سـلام' collate Persian_100_cs_as_ws = N'سلام' collate Persian_100_cs_as_ws
            then 1 
            else 0 
end
```

Both output results are 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Binary collation.

```
select 
case 
    when 
        N'سـلام' = N'سلام' COLLATE Persian_100_BIN
            then 1 
            else 0 
end
```

Results in 0

EDIT:
Running the result of the following query, confirms that only the binary collations will identify the difference.

```
SELECT N'select ''' + name + N''', case when N''سـلام'' = N''سلام'' COLLATE ' + name + N'  then 1 else 0 end ' 
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
```